# How to replace a letter with another letter in a name in MySQL?

Tags: mysql, sql

I have a table in MySQL named `singers`. I want to replace a letter with another letter in a name of entire rows.
For example:
I have a name `abcd` in entire rows, so I want to replace with `xyz` instead of `abcd` in entire rows.

Answer (score 0):

https://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.0/en/string-functions.html#function_replace

```
UPDATE singers SET `your_column` = REPLACE(`your_column`, 'abcd', 'xyz')
```

Answer (score 0):

[How to find and replace text in mysql](https://techjourney.net/how-to-find-and-replace-text-in-mysql-database-using-sql/)

```
update TABLE_NAME set FIELD_NAME = replace(FIELD_NAME, 'find this string', 'replace found string with this string');
```

Comment: In your case, it would be

UPDATE singers SET COLUMN_NAME = REPLACE(COLUMN_NAME, 'abcd', 'xyz');